# Maven release:prepare TAG before commit

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration

Is there any way to `TAG` the code with the `POM`s before the incremental? I do not need to tag afterwards - only before will do. 
I've checked several threads here and in bug reports and i find nothing conclusive. My release is pretty simple. Right now i am at version `4.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and i want this to be the tag (`app-name-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT`). Is this possible? I see a lot of reports for this functionality to be broken.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: what did you mean by you don't need to tag afterwards? Is it only the version update you want to tag?

Comment: By tagging you meant creating annotation in source repository(like GIT).  Then there are specific commands available in source repository which will enable tagging.  If you meant pushing snapshot version to nexus repository, then you could mvn deploy, with appropriate in changes in pom.xml specifying snapshot repository and maven plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to understand the release plugin purpose.

release:prepare:

```
1) run build, with tests
2) check no snapshot dependencies
3) remove snapshot from version (4.0.0 in your case)
4) tag this version in source control (4.0.0 in your case)
5) increment version to next snapshot (4.0.1-SNAPSHOT in your case)
```

release:perform

```
1) checkout tag
2) build with tests
3) deploy released version to repository (4.0.0 in your case)
```

You will then have an immutable binary in the repository and an matching source code tag at  version 4.0.0.